# GET blob from sql database Golang

Tags: go

```
 import (
       "database/sql"
       "encoding/json"
       "fmt"

       _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
   ) 
   type User struct {
       Name string  `json:name`
       Picture []uint8 `json:picture`
    }
    func main(){
       //straight to the query
       rows, err := 'SELECT name, picture FROM ms_users' // picture is longblob type in database
       checkErr(err)

       var usr User
       for rows.Next(){
          err = rows.Scan(&usr.Name, &usr.Picture)
          checkErr(err)
       }
       jsn, err := json.Marshal(usr)
       fmt.Printf("%v, "string(jsn))
    }
```

With above code, I only get name value but the picture is empty.
How do I store blob value from databse to struct ?
Any answer will be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Which database/driver? Also, check the `len(usr.Picture)` to make sure it isn't related to the `json` package.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear go-sql-driver/mysql

Comment: You might have to utilize https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#RawBytes , but I wouldn't write that off as the end solution yet.

Comment: Use `[]byte` instead of `[]uint8`. `[]byte` is listed here, but `[]uint8` is not. https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scan

Comment: I change to []byte but still empty :/

Comment: Try using `string` https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/336127359b09c9c8164e39c4c44f4d36ef081dc8/driver_test.go#L972

Comment: @mkopriva It's WORKS! man, many thanks!

Comment: Odd that a `string` works when a `[]byte` doesn't. Internally a `string` IS a `[]byte`.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear seems like they handle a [byte slice](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/ae5a66df4d33ba404d639bd0fc9189cd5ee79bcf/packets.go#L1012-L1029) just the same as [string](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/ae5a66df4d33ba404d639bd0fc9189cd5ee79bcf/packets.go#L1036-L1049) apart from that a [nil byte slice](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/ae5a66df4d33ba404d639bd0fc9189cd5ee79bcf/packets.go#L1031-L1034), ...

Comment: which `usr.Picture` would be in this case, is set to [nil](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/ae5a66df4d33ba404d639bd0fc9189cd5ee79bcf/packets.go#L1144-L1146)... that is, if i'm reading the code correctly.

Comment: @mkopriva I was digging in there for that switch, but `packets.go` didn't seem the obvious file to check. Thanks for the links

Comment: no worries, although I'm really not sure whether my assumption is correct because of  this [test](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/driver_test.go#L852-L867)

Answer (score 10):

I'm relatively new to GO I encountered this question while searching a solution for a similar problem I was able to find a solution.

When you get BLOB data from the database you get it as type []byte your struct can look like this below

```
type User struct {
   Name string  `json:name`
   Picture []byte`json:picture`
}
```

I guess you can process the byte array according to you need later. In my case I needed a JSON object so I unmarshalled it to a type interface{} variable.